# initialization with ' ... ' expected for aggregate object

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to write a code in C++ that allows you to enter some text and it will open a website with the variable s_input appended to it. However, I get this error:

> 'system' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const
>   char *'

I get that error for the last line you see.

```
cin >> s_input;
transform(s_input.begin(), s_input.end(), s_input.begin(), tolower);
s_input = "start http://website.com/" + s_input + "/0/7/0";
system(s_input);
```

I am new to C++ and this is more of a learning program.. So please show as many examples as possible! Thanks!

Comment: You really mean `system` API? Use `ShellExecute`, `ShellExecuteEx` or `CreateProcess`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `s_input` is a `std::string` (I'm betting it is):

```
system(s_input.c_str());
```

The function `system` takes a `const char*` as parameter, as the error message clearly states.