# Fixing "const-ness" Issue with "IntelliSence: Initialiation..." error

Tags: c++, scheduled-tasks, constants, intellisense

Alright, I am aware of my issue at the moment. I am trying to convert a string to a TCHAR. The error I get looks like this:

> IntelliSense: initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object

The code I am using, large in part is from an msdn [guide/tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383624(v=vs.85).aspx) where I am looking to replace lines about filling in a username and password based on briefly stored information. The guide asks for a prompt for username and password, however due to the requirements from my higher-ups, I can't do this. This C++ code is being ran as part of a larger C# program to add to the Microsoft Task Scheduler as C# doesn't have the functionality (as far as I can see).

```
string functionName;
std::wstring functionNameW;
LPCWSTR functionNameR;
```

[insert irrelevant code]

```
ifstream myfile ("~~string location~~");
if (myfile.is_open())
{

    ...

    getline (myfile,functionName);
    functionNameW = s2ws(functionName);
    functionNameR = functionNameW.c_str();
    //TCHAR of name
    TCHAR *paramName=new TCHAR[functionName.size()+1];
    paramName[functionName.size()]=0;
    //As much as we'd love to, we can't use memcpy() because
    //sizeof(TCHAR)==sizeof(char) may not be true:
    std::copy(functionName.begin(),functionName.end(),paramName);
}
```

[insert irrelevant code]

```
TCHAR pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH] = paramName;  //apparently not keep "const"-ness
```

So basically I read in the desired name from a .txt file. I then convert this name into multiple string types that are required at various stages throughout my code.

Now I have read up on this error from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693331/c-error-initialization-with-expected-for-aggregate-object) [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944079/what-is-wrong-here) [submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531345/initialization-with-expected-for-aggregate-object), but I run into the problem that many of these threads are specifically about arrays/vectors **AND there do not seem to be any answers on how to actually deal with this problem**. Everyone merely states that this error is attempting to say you are putting a "const" value into a non-const variable (or vice-versa).

So, is there a way I can get through this error? If it is an error dealing with "const"-ness, can I de-const a variable when placing it in a new location?

If you're looking for a "**full" mini-version of the code**, I guess it would look like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"                     //created when MVS made this
#include <fstream>                      //need to read
#include <string>                       //need to read
#define _WIN32_DCOM                     //from msdn Task Manager Demo
#include <windows.h>                    //from msdn Task Manager Demo
#include <iostream>                     //from msdn Task Manager Demo
#include <stdio.h>                      //from msdn Task Manager Demo
#include <comdef.h>                     //from msdn Task Manager Demo
#include <wincred.h>                    //from msdn Task Manager Demo
//  Include the task header file.       //from msdn Task Manager Demo
#include <taskschd.h>                   //from msdn Task Manager Demo
# pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")   //from msdn Task Manager Demo
# pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")    //from msdn Task Manager Demo
# pragma comment(lib, "credui.lib")     //from msdn Task Manager Demo
using namespace std;

std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

int __cdecl wmain()
{
    string functionName;
    std::wstring functionNameW;
    LPCWSTR functionNameR;

    ifstream myfile ("~~string location~~");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        getline (myfile,functionName);
        functionNameW = s2ws(functionName);
        functionNameR = functionNameW.c_str();
        //TCHAR of name
        TCHAR *paramName=new TCHAR[functionName.size()+1];
        paramName[functionName.size()]=0;
        //As much as we'd love to, we can't use memcpy() because
        //sizeof(TCHAR)==sizeof(char) may not be true:
        std::copy(functionName.begin(),functionName.end(),paramName);
    }

    TCHAR pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH] = paramName;  //apparently not keep "const"-ness
}
```

Comment: What is `paramUserName`? Please present a real [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit apologies, it was meant to be 'paramName'. This is the smallest amount of code I can trim down to that creates the same problem. It is just a means of converting from _C++ String_ to _C++ TCHAR_.

Comment: I can guarantee you can trim it more! But the testcase must be _complete_, which this isn't. Please follow the link I gave you (you were also presented with this information when you joined).

Comment: What would you expect `TCHAR pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH] = paramName;` to do?  Copy the string?  If you want to copy the data then you should do that with `_tcscpy` or whatever.  Your short example doesn't compile because `paramName` isn't in scope, but if you correct that and try to compile you'll see the error.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I _believe_ I added at complete version to the bottom of the original post. If it is not as trimmed as possible I am not sure where I can trim it. C++ is somewhat foreign to me, especially in this type of use. I am currently on internship and the only person working on this project outside of the scope of what I've learned previously so I am learning as I go and have hit this wall.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I was under the impression that line would assign or copy the value of `paramName` to `pszName`. The code in the original version that I linked read as `TCHAR pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH] = "";` Where would the `_tcscpy` go? I have never used C++ for this type of work. How would I correct the scope issue as well?

Comment: For the scope issue it would seem you might need to learn a bit more about C++ before you try to use it.  That's quite a broad subject.  There's already an example of copying string data in your code which I assume you wrote?  You would want to do something similar with `std::copy` or `_tcscpy` to copy a different string.  I realize you may have inherited this project, but for a beginner the `TCHAR` stuff will cause you more confusion than it is worth, especially since you have a fair amount of non TCHAR code already.

Comment: @RetiredNinja this is a project I am tasked with converting (very) old code from VB to C#, and while I am comfortable with C#, it doesn't have the needed libraries(?) to use the Microsoft Task Scheduler API. My coding background is more focused on Java, C# for Unity, and various game engines, so while C++ is somewhat similar to these languages there are many small differences.

Comment: @ZeroAurora You allocate `paramName` locally, copy a string to it, and then do nothing with it except leak memory.  C++ is not Java -- that memory is leaked if you don't call `delete[]`.

Comment: @ZeroAurora When you say "... [C#] doesn't have the needed libraries(?) to use the Microsoft Task Scheduler API..." have you tried using COM interop?  In a C# project's Solution Explorer right click on references, select Add reference, then select the COM tab on the left-hand side and type 'sched' in the search COM box.  You should see the TaskScheduler type library in the search results.  Add a reference to that type library and then check out the Interop.TaskScheduler assembly in the Object browser.

Comment: @FrankBoyne I am aware that C# and WPF have a Task Scheduler in their libraries, however I need the task to run outside of the programming environment. My understanding of C#'s task scheduler is that is doesn't allow for what I am tasked with making.

Comment: @ZeroAurora I wasn't suggesting you use the [TaskScheduler class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx).  I was suggesting you use [COM Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k.aspx) to invoke the [Windows Task Scheduler COM Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383600.aspx) from a C# program.